# RegEx for decimal puts 0 (zero) in the text field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

I am trying the following `RegEx` to validate the decimal value like

```
 [RegularExpression("^(?:\\d{1,100000000}(?:\\.\\d{0,6})?)?$")]
        [Range(double.MinValue,double.MaxValue)]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

rendering in the view like

```
    <div class="editor-field">
       <%:Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Amount)%>       
       <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Amount) %>
    </div>
```

the problem is it puts a `0` in the textbox by default, please guide me find out the problem, also if there is a better way to validate the decimal field please do mention...

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375729/mvc3-3-decimal-places-on-type-double-with-leading-zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try settings the type of your Amount property to nullable:

```
public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
```

Comment: yup it worked for me, i got bz and forgot to mark it as an answer... tnx for your time