# Can not type a double in a textbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm working on an mvc .net web application and I'm using Entity Framework for generating Model. I have classes that contain attributes that are doubles. My problem is that when I use `@HTML.EditorFor(model => model.Double_attribute)` and test my application I can't type a double in that editor, I only can type integers. (I'm using Razor engine for views)How to solve this? Thanks.

Update : I discovered that I can type a double having this format #,### (3 numbers after the comma but I do not want to make user type a specific format, I want to accept all formats (1 or more numbers after the comma)
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Regards

Comment: Is client validation enabled?
Did you try to use different decimal separators: . and , (point and comma)?

Comment: This is abnormal it works, you probably have some JS scripts which create an issue. Remove js reference and try to see.

Comment: yes it is activated. I tryed with both of them but it didn't work

Comment: @HediNaily, Can you also post your model definition?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference but have you tried, `@HTML.EditorFor(model => model.Double_attribute)`? Also, post your model code, do you have any attributes on `Model.Double_attribute`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use add notations :

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,##0.000#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public double? Double_attribute{ get; set; }
```

And now... voila : you can use the double in your view :

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Double_attribute)
```

For other formats you could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375729/mvc3-3-decimal-places-on-type-double-with-leading-zero) or just google "DataFormatString double" your desired option for this field.

Comment: I can only type a double having this format #,### (3 numbers after the comma but I do not want to make user type a specific format, I want to accept all formats (1 or more numbers after the comma)

Answer (score 0):

try to use custom databinder:

```
public class DoubleModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel( ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext )
    {
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue( bindingContext.ModelName );
        var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;

        try
        {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDouble( valueResult.AttemptedValue,
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
        }
        catch ( FormatException e )
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add( e );
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add( bindingContext.ModelName, modelState );
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

and register binder in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start ()
{
    ...
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add( typeof( double ), new DoubleModelBinder() );
}
```