# typing a double in a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC3 - 3 decimal places on type double with leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375729/mvc3-3-decimal-places-on-type-double-with-leading-zero)
>   [Can not type a double in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251832/can-not-type-a-double-in-a-textbox)

I'm using Entity Framework for generating Model in an asp.net web application. I have classes that contain attributes that are doubles. My problem is that when I use:

```
@HTML.EditorFor(model => model.Double_attribute)
```

and test my application I can't type a `double` in that editor, I only can type integers. (I'm using the Razor view engine) How to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7381179/1003016[this link having your answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7381179/1003016

Comment: what exactly you write in this textbox? Try to change '.' on ',' or vice-versa

Comment: Why do ask this twice? You already asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251832/can-not-type-a-double-in-a-textbox