# ASP.NET MVC Form and double fields

Tags: asp.net, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an asp.net mvc portal to manage GPS coordinates using localDB. My model is:

```
public class GpsCoordinateViewModel
{
    double Latitute { get; set; }
    double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

the autogenerated adn related View to create a new GpsCoordinate is:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>GpsCoordinateViewModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Latitude)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Latitude)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Latitude)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Longitude)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Longitude)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Longitude)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

the problem is that when I insert as Latitude: 41.213321 and  Longitude: 12.123432 (eg), using breakpoin local values are: Latitude: 41213321 Longitude: 12123432.
I need to use double because of location's accuracy, but how?

I also read this questions :
[How should I use EditorFor() in MVC for a currency/money type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080451/how-should-i-use-editorfor-in-mvc-for-a-currency-money-type)

[MVC3 - 3 decimal places on type double with leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375729/mvc3-3-decimal-places-on-type-double-with-leading-zero)

but the solutions didn't work for me.
Any suggestion?

EDIT:
My webconfig  is:

```
<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>

<!--
    Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
    after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
    MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
    To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
    controller or action.
-->
<pages
    validateRequest="false"
    pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=number">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=number" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
</pages>
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

Comment: Are you saying that if you enter values with a decimal point, the values are then received as whole number in your contrller?

Comment: Hi von v.
yes, exactly

Comment: That's interesting. Even without those dataannotation formatting it should work. I don't even think culture info has something to do with this as you do not get a separator at all! Hmm...

Comment: @vonv. for instance cultureinfo for French(Belgium) (fr-BE) a valid number is (123.456.789,00) here . is for digit grouping and , is decimal symbol.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Is there a country whose decimal symbol is "empty"?

Comment: Yes you are right, even if with the fr-BE culture "41.213321" should be converted to C# double 41213321.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might be caused by cultureinfo, some culture use `,` instead of `.` for decimal separator. try setting the following in web.config,

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
</system.web>
```

hope this helps

Comment: it works but not so good. The form's fields let me insert short number(only 3 numbers afeter , ) and then when I create a new DbGeography (See System.Data.Spatial) object I have a general exception.

Comment: Are you using "en-US"? if using, does 41.213321 not binding correctly?

Comment: I copy and paste <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" /> in my system.web tag. If i use the , (eg: 41,213321) the form show me this: "The field Latitude must be a number". If i use 41.213321, the break point show me 41213321.00. In both case the application go in catch and it doesn't insert a new GpsCoordinate. now i edit my question to show you my <system.web/>

Comment: Have you used any DataAnnotations on 'Latitute', 'Latitute' properties on 'GpsCoordinateViewModel' class?

Comment: as you can see up, no i didn't

Answer (score 0):

Well then, Use the String as a DataType and Parse it as a Decimal value Later from the Controller.

Answer (score -1):

Use Decimal Instead of Double as Your Data Type, and That might Help.

```
public class GpsCoordinateViewModel
{
    decimal Latitute { get; set; }
    decimal Longitude { get; set; }
}
```