# ASP.NET MVC Passing a double to an action from ajax call (I'm receiving a null)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not able to pass a double to my action (at least not in a proper way).

This is my action:

```
  public JsonResult SomeAction(double? n = null)
  {
      // ...
  }
```

And this is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/SomeController/SomeAction',
    data: {
        "n": 1.5
    },
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

The number 1.5 is not being passed to the action. When debugging in serverside, **I'm receiving a null instead.**

If I change the ajax to this:

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/SomeController/SomeAction',
    data: {
        "n": "1,5"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

I do get a 1.5 in serverside.

**What change in serverside do I need to do so that the first ajax call works?**

Another thing that worked for me was using the first ajax call and changing the signature of the action to this:

```
public JsonResult SomeAction(string n = "")
{
       double parsedN = Convert.ToDouble(n);
}
```

Of course both solutions suck

Comment: why was downvoted? please explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What finally worked was the answer of this other question:
[ASP.NET MVC Form and double fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058760/asp-net-mvc-form-and-double-fields)

Quoting here:

> Might be caused by cultureinfo, some culture use , instead of . for
>   decimal separator. try setting the following in web.config,

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
  </system.web>
```