# Displayformat fails to format

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

I have picked up an MVC solution and I am trying to format a double variable to 2 decimal places on a form table. In the modelview it is set using

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

before the public double declaration
But this is not passed through to the table. The table is created using javascript.

I have tried to modify the variable in the javascript but that fails.
here is an extract of the code used

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Journey distance in miles</div>
    <div class="col-md-9">@Model.Miles</div>
</div>
```

The web page just displays the value without any formatting
I am new to this, so apologize in advance if it is obvious

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375729/mvc3-3-decimal-places-on-type-double-with-leading-zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your displayformat isn't taking.

I'm guessing Model.Miles isn't a string. If not.. try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Journey distance in miles</div>
    <div class="col-md-9">@Model.Miles.ToString("#.##")</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. I had used zeros instead of hash. All working now.